# using timer.elapsed in vb

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a VB sub as follows:

```
Private timer As New System.Timers.Timer()

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        Try
            timer.Elapsed += New ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime)
            Dim timerTime As Integer = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("timer"))
            timer.Interval = timerTime
            timer.Enabled = True
            Dim worker = New System.Threading.Thread(DoWork)
            worker.Name = "Happy"
            worker.IsBackground = False
            worker.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

But the problems is I am used to C# code and have a small project in VB and `timer.Elapsed += New ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime)` gives an error of cannot be called directly and I have to use a raise event.

Same goes foe OnElapsedTime and DoWork. Those are sub's in my program.

Why can I use them and why is the error coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) in VB.NET to register events programmatically:

```
AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnElapsedTime
```